# Updating minutes in a Timer for Windows store app

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to create a timer for my windows store app, 
I've been able to update secondes,but not minutes,
minutes gets its value from a combobox

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
  {

    int secCount = 0;
    DispatcherTimer timerCount = new DispatcherTimer();
    TextBlock time = new TextBlock();
    int m;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        timerCount.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        timerCount.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(timer_tick);
        m = Convert.ToInt32(cMinutes.SelectedValue);
    }


    private void timer_tick(object sender, object e)
    {


        time.Text = cHours.SelectedItem + ":" + m + ":" + secCount;
        timer.Children.Add(time); //timer is the main grid


        secCount--;
        if(secCount < 0)
        {
            secCount = 59;
            m--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is an issue in your code, you are adding the TextBlock `time` to the `timer` Grid repeatedly, and you should get an exception complaining that the TextBlock is already one of the Grid's children.

**The answer to your question**

You need to update cMinutes' SelectedValue or SelectedIndex.

**Some enhancements:**

I move the initialization of the fields `timerCount` and `time` into the MainPage's constructor, it is a good practice to initialize all the fields in one place.

Since int (`secCount` and `m`) is default to 0, you don't need to set the initial values for ints.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    int secCount;
    int m;
    DispatcherTimer timerCount; //declare here, initialize in constructor
    TextBlock time; //declare here, initialize in constructor

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        time = new TextBlock();
        timer.Children.Add(time); //fix: only add ONCE

        //populate the Combobox
        cMinutes.Items.Add(0); 
        cMinutes.Items.Add(1);
        cMinutes.Items.Add(2);
        cMinutes.SelectedIndex = 2;

        m = Convert.ToInt32(cMinutes.SelectedValue);

        timerCount = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerCount.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        timerCount.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(timer_tick);
        timerCount.Start();
    }

    private void timer_tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        time.Text = cHours.SelectedItem + ":" + m + ":" + secCount;

        secCount--;
        if (secCount < 0)
        {
            secCount = 59;
            m--;

            if (cMinutes.Items.Contains(m)) //fix: update Combobox's selected value
                cMinutes.SelectedValue = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work,it always retrieve the 3rd item from the combobox , also I didn't get those lines you've added                                                                            if (cMinutes.Items.Contains(m)) 
                cMinutes.SelectedValue = m;

Comment: See the comment `//populate the Combobox`, I set 3 items and select the 3rd so that the code could be compiled and demo the issue. And `if (cMinutes.Items.Contains(m)) cMinutes.SelectedValue = m;` was where I updated the Combobox, you were looking for a way to update the Combobox, right?

Comment: I no ,I just wanted to update the minutes in the time text block after getting its value from cMinutes comboBox